# Returning multiple classes that extend component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We are trying to generalize a function that will generate and return multiple buttons and modals. Currently we are running into an issue where attempting to return multiple components in a array results in an error message popping up, with the other alternative of returning the render functions in a array of the multiple components resulting in no errors but failing to render the modals but showing the buttons.

How can we go about this or a better way to design this in a way that'll work?

````
import {Button, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';


class ChemistryInfoComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {show: false};
  }
  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({show: true});
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({show: false});
  }
  

  render() {
    return <div> 
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleShow}>
          Basic Blood Chemistry
      </Button>

      <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Basic Button!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>;
  }
}



function OrderingPage() {
  var component1 = new ChemistryInfoComponent();
  var component2 = new ChemistryInfoComponent();
  var component3 = new ChemistryInfoComponent();
  return [component1, component2, component3]; // "Objects are not valid as a React child"
  // return [component1.render(), component2.render()] => looses context of this (modals don't pop up)
}

export default OrderingPage ```


The error message in question:
```Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, handleShow, handleClose, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.```
````

Comment: `var component1 = <ChemistryInfoComponent />;` etc. Don't instantiate them.

Comment: Does that still work when each of them has specific information related to it? Like if button 1 was "basic" and button 2 was "advanced" etc. Not seeing how to pass that information.

Comment: Never mind, read up on how props work with JSX. Thanks for the help!
(var component1 = <ChemistryInfoComponent name="basic"/>;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts please submit your solution as an answer.